# Can I style the Alt+F2 prompt?

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, prompt

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10. My main issue with it is that the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> prompt darkens the entire screen underneath it while open and I find the resulting blink overstimulating.  I looked on Google to no avail.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it. Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Always [edit] your question to add important info to the the question, leaving a comment is not good enough.

Comment: Yes, I have managed to do it yesterday. It boils down to overriding the gnome-shell UI's [lightbox.js](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/gnome-3-36/js/ui/lightbox.js). Here is my detailed answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1305510/1157519