# Changing the dark overlay background on the Activity- and Apps-overview screens, as well as behind dialog boxes (Gnome 3)

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, theme-development

On Ubuntu **20.04.1 LTS**

Gnome version according the Settings app's "About" tab: **3.36.8**

```
gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.36.4
```

Theme: **Yaru** (the default; not the "light", not the "dark")

When I press the super key, or activate the hot corner, the "overview" screen comes up, where I can search for apps, settings, documents, and more:

[image: screenshot of Gnome dash]

**Problem / Challenge:**

I find this overlay too dark compared to how my desktop normally looks; each time I have to use it, I find it has an intrusive impact on the experience, and it's a tiring exercise for my eyes to adjust.

I would like to make this overlay somewhat lighter / brighter.

I have looked into the settings in `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock` with dconf-editor, but I have not found anything for it. (I have not enabled the "Ubuntu Dock" additional Gnome shell extension in Tweaks.)

Then I copied the Yaru theme from `/usr/share/themes/` to `~/.themes/`, and activated it with Gnome-Tweaks.

In `~/.themes/My-Yaru/gtk-3.20/` I have exported the true content of, and overwritten the file `gtk.css` with

```
gresource extract gtk.gresource /com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru/3.20/gtk.css > gtk.css
```

Now, instead of the original single line of import statement, it has 12637 lines of CSS in it.

I did try to identify the CSS selector of the dash overlay, but I have not found anything. Then I was looking for declarations of radial gradients (because this overlay seems to have a radial gradient on it), but what I have found seems unrelated to this overlay.

What can I do now? Am I on the right track at all?

If yes, how could I enable a Gnome debug mode that — comparably to web browsers' developer-tools — would interactively reveal the CSS selector of the this overlay?

If this is not the right direction, then how could I achieve the goal — preferably without having to install an entirely different theme?

Comment: You should not touch gtk concept.. It purely depends on gnome-shell theme..

Comment: @UnKNOWn and what is the way to find the gnome-shell code and to override it? Do I need to fork an entire gnome shell extension? Which one? Where is it?

Comment: Excellent hint, now I have found `/usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css`, which has `#dash` selectors in it. Also on gnome-look.org I have found the gnome shell themes category, downloaded a few, and they also have this selector. Now I must attend to errands, but will continue investigating soon. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer compat:**

Ubuntu 20.04.1,
gnome-shell version: 3.36.4
display server: X.Org Server

The dark background with a radial gradient comes from gnome shell UI's lightbox.js.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/gnome-3-36/js/ui/lightbox.js

**There seem to be 3 approaches:**

- via parameters (?)
- via js code override, utilizing "gresource overlays"
- via css, through creating a custom gnome-shell theme

### Via parameters supplied to gnome-shell UI's lightbox.js

I don't know much about this. I haven't found anything relevant in `dconf-editor`, plus two out of the three interesting parameters seemed to be hardcoded to me. So I went for the code.

### Via overriding gnome-shell UI's lighbox.js code

Changing lighbox.js behavior impacts not only the Activity- and Apps-overview screens, but other dialogs too, such as: *Run a Command*, *Authentication required*, *Power off*, and more.

On Ubuntu 20.04, the file is normally packaged up inside `/usr/lib/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so`.

To override it, one needs to extract a copy of it, and ask Gnome to use this copy.

Create this directory structure, and `cd` there in a terminal:

```
~/.gnome-shell-custom-overlays/ui/
```

```bsh
# You should be here:
~/.gnome-shell-custom-overlays/ui$
```

While in this directory, do the following:

```bsh
# Make a copy of the resource:
cp /usr/lib/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so .

# To see all of its contents:
gresource list libgnome-shell.so

# To obtain lightbox.js:
gresource extract libgnome-shell.so /org/gnome/shell/ui/lightbox.js > lightbox.js

# If the extraction was successful, our copy of the resource can
# (probably should?) be removed.
rm libgnome-shell.so
```

Edit the lightbox.js file; change the three variables near the top, as follows:

```javascript
// Old:
//var DEFAULT_FADE_FACTOR = 0.4;
//var VIGNETTE_BRIGHTNESS = 0.5;
//var VIGNETTE_SHARPNESS = 0.7;

// New:
var DEFAULT_FADE_FACTOR = 0.1;
var VIGNETTE_BRIGHTNESS = 0.8;
var VIGNETTE_SHARPNESS = 0.2;
```

Now we need to tell Gnome about our modified file. Put the following line into `~/.profile`:

```bsh
export G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS="/org/gnome/shell=$HOME/.gnome-shell-custom-overlays"
```

The term "overlays" here doesn't refer to the lightbox overlay; rather, it suggests how this Gnome/GTK resource overriding feature works.

**Important note:** before I did all this, I already had the **`libgtk-3-dev`** package installed on my system. It's for development / debugging, just like the resource overlays feature seems to be so. Therefore right now I cannot determine whether respecting the `G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS` environment variable depends on the presence of this package or not... Just in case be ready to install it...

Anyhow: for the changes to take effect, log out and log back in.

**Further tweaking**

To see the effect of further tweaks on the lightbox parameters, reloading the Gnome shell after each edit is necessary. It can be done by issuing the `r` command through the *Run command* dialog (revealed by Alt+F2).

**Interesting:** In my experience, when one saves the lightbox.js file with a syntax error within, the *Run command* dialog doesn't *seem to appear* any more. But it may be "there", just not "visible". In such case, proceed as if it was there: fix the syntax and save the file, hit Alt+F2, then `r`, then Enter.

**Further important considerations** regarding the resources overlay feature's potential impact on system stability are discussed [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1317692/1157519).

References / literature:

- [Credit to Superuser Q/A](https://superuser.com/a/1387165/1257174)
- [Gnome devs' reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html#GResource.description)
- [Gnome cookbook on Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Tips_and_tricks#Removing_film_holes/film_strip_from_video_thumbnails_in_Nautilus)

### Via CSS (gnome-shell custom theme)

If you managed to override lightbox.js, then this part can offer just a few more adjustments to polish the experience a bit further.

If you did not override lightbox.js however, then this part can offer an additional workaround with limited usefulness for the Activity- and Apps overview screens.

(Also, the following was my original answer to the problem, before I could put my hand on the javascript override above.)

**Using custom Gnome shell themes**

The Gnome Tweaks app, as well as a Gnome shell extension, "User Themes" (part of the `gnome-shell-extensions` package, available via apt install), are needed for this.

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks gnome-shell-extensions
```

Open the Tweaks app, and enable the "User Themes" extension on the "Extensions" tab.

**Creating a custom Gnome shell theme**

This part is not proven to be the best method; it's just that I found this way.

Create the following directory structure:

```
~/.themes/my-gnome-shell-theme/gnome-shell/
```

copy this file (the default Yaru theme's shell theme implementation):

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

into this newly created directory, so you end up with this:

```
~/.themes/my-gnome-shell-theme/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource
```

Opening this directory in the terminal, `gresource list gnome-shell-theme.gresource` reveals the contents of this newly copied file.

A **custom-made script** can help extracting all the contents.

The script's contents could be something like this, or better (I'm not a bash scripting expert) (I already know that people don't like backticks any more):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

currentdir=$(pwd);

# For regular themes:
# gresource_name="gtk.gresource"
# For shell themes:
gresource_name="gnome-shell-theme.gresource"

for resource in `gresource list ${currentdir}/${gresource_name}`;
do
    echo $resource
    filename=`basename ${resource}`
    gresource extract $currentdir/$gresource_name $resource > $currentdir/$filename
done
```

**Note:** this custom script does not reproduce the directory structure prescribed within the .gresource file; instead, it places the files in the target (current) directory in a flat fashion. However, it prints the definition of each resource it encounters, complete with its originally intended/defined path. While it does not seem to be always necessary, in some cases (e.g. when broken icons or widget backgrounds are encountered) it might be worth considering to rearrange the files into a directory structure according to what the definitions suggest. Note, that I left the original .gresource file in the directory.

**Alternative extractor script:** more such scripts can be found by searching for the string "do gresource extract" either on this site or elsewhere on the internet.

Having run the extractor script, and then quickly securing a backup of the original file,

```
cp gnome-shell.css gnome-shell.css.bak
```

the extracted `gnome-shell.css` file is ready for editing.

**gnome-shell developer tool**

It's called [Looking Glass](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/LookingGlass). It can be activated by issuing the `lg` command through the *Run command* dialog (revealed by Alt+F2).

**CSS tweaks**

Below changes worked best for my drab desktop background color; but with some color tweaks it may be useful for any case.

CSS works in such ways that definitions made towards the end of a file can override definitions written earlier in the same file. That's why it's not necessary to scatter edits all over the file; just appending the right thing at the very end does the job. That's what I appended to `gnome-shell.css`:

```css
/* Activity-Overview-related */

/* Covers up the dark lightbox overlay with a lighter semi-opaque tone.
   This may be needed only if lightbox.js is not overridden. */

/*
#overview {
    background-color: rgba(210,202,194,0.6);
}
*/

.search-section-content {
    /* This has text on it; for eligibility, keep it more opaque. */
    background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.5);
}
.workspace-thumbnails {
    /* Plain background area, may be pretty transparent. */
    background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.25);
}

/* A less harsh workspace-switcher popup. */

.workspace-switcher-container {
    background-color: rgba(100, 96, 92, 0.45);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.ws-switcher-active-up,
.ws-switcher-active-down,
.ws-switcher-active-left,
.ws-switcher-active-right {
    background-color: rgba(215, 86, 41, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid #cc4414;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #ffffff; }

/* Misc. */

.switcher-list, .osd-window, .resize-popup {
    /* A bit softer Alt+Tab popup.
     * This has text on it; for eligibility, keep it more opaque. */
    background-color: rgba(100, 96, 92, 0.85);
}
```

**Enabling the custom theme**

In the Tweaks app's "Appearance" tab, in the "Themes" section, there's a field labeld "Shell". The new custom theme should be available in the select widget. Remember, for this widget to be active, the "User themes" Gnome shell extension needs to be enabled.

**Making CSS modifications to take effect**

Method 1: Issuing the `r` command through the *Run command* dialog (revealed by Alt+F2) reloads the shell; it should also pick up the new CSS changes.

Method 2: Switching back and forth between the default and custom shell themes seemed to go more smooth and graceful in comparison to Method 1. The theme-switching can be achieved on the Tweaks app's UI, or via `gsettings` on the cli, as follows:

```bsh
# For resetting to default, the argument can apparently be either
# an empty string: '' or: default.
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name ''

# The custom theme's name is the name of its directory in ~/.themes/
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme name my-gnome-shell-theme
```

**Recovery from a messed up custom theme**

If needed, it's possible to switch back to the default theme by executing the above `gsettings set` command in a virtual console (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F3) (without the need to start a graphical session).

Comment: Ok two comments.  First, I have found that I can bypass all this work of unpacking and customizing by simply editing libgnome-shell.so directly in emacs as root (it seems to be binary safe and I've made a backup first) and making sure that I only overwrite characters directly in the embedded source code.  When I do this, as soon as I save the file gnome detects this and restarts itself.

Comment: Second, unfortunately it doesn't seem that modifying any of the vars you have identified makes any difference as to how bright the lock screen or background when I hit the super key to show all my windows... at least not enough difference to get a pure white or black color.

Comment: @Michael indeed, I have seen traces of inspiration on this site about editing the original libgnome-shell.so with a so-called "hex-editor". But, since I already have my problem solved with this above introduced method, I kept postponing the experiment with the hex-editor.