# Ubuntu 18.04 - how to change the transparency of the background under the Gnome modal?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

**The summary of the essence of the issue is brief:**

how to increase the transparency of the background or completely remove the transparent background under the modal here:

[image]

**Explaining the essence of the issue in detail:**

I try to formulate the question as clearly and simply as possible.
As far as I could find out, my question is about customizing the Gnome Shell theme that comes with Ubuntu by default.

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Gnome version 3.28
(screen:

[image]

The system has been updated. The default Shell theme is used
(screen:

[image]

Next, I will attach a screen displaying my problem, but first I will try to describe in words.

**Problem:**

I use several keyboard layouts, I need Latin and Cyrillic.
The keyboard layout identifier contains the designation of multiple locales
(screen:

[image]).

At the moment when Ubuntu displays a modal window for me on the screen with a request to enter the superuser password, or at that moment when I use the command input window, which can be invoked by the hotkey [Alt + F2], under the modal window you can see a transparent overlay, which is radial darkens towards the edges of the screen. Thus, the keyboard layout indicator appears in a very darkened form and it is difficult for me to see what information it displays at this moment.
(screen:

[image]).
([image]
)

**Question:**

How can I increase the transparency of the background of the matte (or completely remove this matte) under the modal window,
so that I can see the text identifier of the keyboard layout clearly enough?

**As far as I could figure it out, possible solutions might be as follows:**

- using an extension from Gnome Extensions.
- configurators like Dconf (relevant for Gnome 3), Gconf (as it turned out - not relevant for Gnome 3).
- customize the Gnome theme yourself by editing its CSS file.
- setting the flag instead of the text identifier of the keyboard layout.

**My personal results:**

- Gnome Extensions: I searched among the extensions, but did not find an extension that would provide a solution to my question.
- configurators like Dconf (relevant for Gnome 3), Gconf (as it turned out - not relevant for Gnome 3):
  I was unable to find the desired setting in these configurators. I even looked for it in the CompizConfig Settings Manager.
- customize the Gnome theme yourself by editing the CSS file:
  I was unable to figure out the name of the class that is responsible for the element's styling properties. Most likely this is the right direction for solving the question, but you need to know the specific CSS selector responsible for the transparent background above the desktop.
- setting the flag instead of the text identifier of the keyboard locale:
  I found on the Internet instructions on how to do this, but in any case it is important for me to get an answer to my question above: how to increase the transparency of the background or completely remove the transparent background above the desktop under the modal window?

Comment: I have a related problem, here is my question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1305080/1157519 I found only a workaround: covering up this dark area — in some limited contexts — with another, semi-transparent element. But that won't help you. However, since then I have arrived to the observation that this radial gradient might be governed by the gnome-shell UI's "lightbox.js". Here's the file (v 3.36) on gitlab.com: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/gnome-3-36/js/ui/lightbox.js From here I couldn't get forward yet...

Comment: I have have just managed to override lightbox.js on 20.04. I have modified only the opacity. Here is how: https://askubuntu.com/a/1305510/1157519 I guess more options could be available by further edits in the file.