# How to hide workspace-switcher popup?

Tags: 20.04, workspaces, workspace-switcher

When switching workspaces the popup *thing* is really annoying.

[image: workspace switcher popup]

Is it possible to disable it?

**EDIT:**
*Anyone wanting to know which method to go with, I support both 24601's and BeastOfCaerbannog's answer. I have tried each's suggestion and found them to work fine.*

Comment: you can install Scroll Panel extension, which does not have this popup when scrolling on Top Panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by installing one of the following GNOME extensions:

- [No Workspace Switcher Popup](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/758/no-workspace-switcher-popup/)

  [image: No Workspace Switcher Popup]
- [Disable Workspace Switcher Popup](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/959/disable-workspace-switcher-popup/)

  [image: Disable Workspace Switcher Popup]

Both work with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 6):

Another extension you can use is [Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/). In the extension's settings disable *Workspace Popup*.

[image: Just Perfection extension settings]

Answer (score 2):

The way I know of is through using CSS in a customized gnome-shell theme.

I have posted a detailed answer leading through the steps of creating a custom gnome-shell-theme based on Ubuntu's default one here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1305510/1157519

Note that the above linked answer is aimed at a specific topic different from this one, so only the second half of the answer applies, starting with the *"Via CSS (gnome-shell custom theme)"* title.

It already contains CSS code modifying this popup. Look for *"A less harsh workspace-switcher popup"* in there.

---

Now I've tried and succeeded in making this widget entirely transparent with CSS.

I have added the following at the end of the file `gnome-shell.css` in the custom gnome-shell theme:

```css
.workspace-switcher-container,
.workspace-switcher-container * {
    background: transparent;    
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

An alternative, (but more intrusive) approach could be:

```css
.workspace-switcher-container {
    margin-left: -9000px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't follow this tip, but I can imagine it being more *safer* option, so thanks for posting.

Comment: Well, to be fair, a custom gnome-shell theme also relies on at least one extension, called "User Themes". And right now it seems to me that if one wants to obtain this extension from an official Ubuntu repo (Universe, in this case), one must install it as part of a bundle of several extensions. But at least it's coming from the Universe repo, which I guess is nice.