# How to disable the popup shown when changing a workspace?

Tags: 20.04, workspaces, gnome-shell-extension

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and I would like to disable the popup shown when changing a workspace:

[image: window between workspace]

Comment: There are extensions that do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide workspace-switcher popup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316680/how-to-hide-workspace-switcher-popup)