# How to change background color of "Show Applications" on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: customization, 22.04

I have tried with Dconf, but I was not able to find how to finetune the background color of the "Show applications" action menu on the Dock.

My idea is to make somewhat a WinXP look, which is why I want to change it to green. I managed to edit the background color of the dock already.

How can I change the background color for specific actions?

Comment: I don't thing it is possible, unless somebody shows you how to update the "relevant" `.css` files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the dark overlay background on the Activity- and Apps-overview screens, as well as behind dialog boxes (Gnome 3)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305080/changing-the-dark-overlay-background-on-the-activity-and-apps-overview-screens)

Comment: @vanadium unfortunately this is not applicable for 22.04. I am also running wayland. That's why I asked it in the first place.

Comment: Not sure if that does not work. There are various methods, all equally complicated. That background color of the application is not related to Wayland.

Comment: I dont know how you can change the background color of the "Show Apps" button, nor to change the background color of the dock. But did you find also the option to change the icon?
Maybe it is possible to make you own icon? Fo me i do not understand why you would customize it "like windows". I hate Windows and Big tech companys like Google, Facebook and Microsoft. https://linuxcool.net/en/instructions/how-to-change-the-show-apps-menu-button-in-ubuntu-gnome-shell/