# How can I add a background on "Show Applications" menu?

Tags: gnome, 22.04

The Show Applications menu has a gray background. Is there any way (or extension) to pick a background for it? (22.04)

Comment: why would you want to? Mostly users spend very little time in `Show Applications` and in the main would use `left windows` key to access the search box for the apps they know are on the system 

Comment: I am pretty sure there were some extensions that could do this for older version of Ubuntu. Maybe check them out, they might still work or maybe get updated? [this old extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/358/activities-configurator/) is probably not working for gnome 42 and not all features were updated for [this one](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/)

Comment: Asked here as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406099/how-to-change-background-color-of-show-applications-on-ubuntu-22-04